# Create factory to obtain current user object at all times from Ionic/Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, factory, firebase-authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to Ionic/Firebase but I've been trying to clean up my code so that everything related to database access is in my factory.

The way I have structured my users is that the uid of any new Authentication, including Facebook or Google, is stored in a uids array, along with the key associated with it. The user is also stored in the users array first (which is where the above key was randomly generated). This allows me to access the current user from the Auth object.

```
{
  "uids" : {
    "7d34fb85-813c-4586-857e-f062aed67f32" : {
      "-KDQDk5vwJXmFngwI7iQ" : {
        "registered" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "-KDQDk5vwJXmFngwI7iQ" : {
      "email" : "something@test.com",
      "firstname" : "TestName",
      "lastname" : "TestLastName",
      "uid" : "7d34fb85-813c-4586-857e-f062aed67f32"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a factory I can call from any controller to get the details of the current user - first name, last name etc.

However, I don't think this is the right way to get things to work. Ideally I want to be able to call `Users.getCurrentUser.firstname` on any controller.

Here are the two factories. What am I doing wrong and how can I restructure my code?

```
/**
 * Authentication service
 */
    app.factory('Auth', ['rootRef', '$firebaseAuth', function (rootRef, $firebaseAuth) {
        return $firebaseAuth(rootRef);
    }]);

/**
 * Anything related to the Users array
 */
app.factory('Users', ['$firebaseArray','$firebaseObject', 'Auth', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, Auth) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://[myfirebaseurl].firebaseio.com");
    var users = $firebaseArray(ref.child('users'));
    var uids = $firebaseArray(ref.child('uids'));

    return {
        all: function () {
            return users;
        },
        get: function (id) {
            // Simple index lookup - I also want to be able to use this if a user lets say clicks a user profile in a list of profiles in the app to view a profile, but currently I have no user_id key in my database - do I need to set this up?
            return users[id];
        },
        getCurrentUser: function () {
            var uid = Auth.$getAuth().uid;
            var key = new Firebase(uids + uid).child();
            var user = new Firebase(users + key).child();
            return $firebaseObject(user);
        }
    }

}])
```

Any help most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see changes.

Answer (score 1):

This will never work:

```
Users.getCurrentUser().firstname
```

Like most of the modern web, loading data in Firebase happens asynchronously. While the data is being loaded (and in Firebase's case, subsequently will be synchronized), the JavaScript code continue to execute.

That is why you have to split the "start loading" from the "when the user data has loaded/is changed" operation.

In AngularFire, you can get the initial data that is loaded for the user, by waiting for the `$loaded()` promise to resolve:

```
var user = $firebaseObject(user);
user.$loaded(function(user) {
  console.log(user.firstname);
});
```

But this is really an anti-pattern, since the user data may subsequently change and that won't your `$loaded()` callback again.

The best way to see what is going on with AngularFire is to simply visualize the objects in your AngularJS view:

```
$scope.user = $firebaseObject(user);
```

And then:

```
<pre> user | json </pre>
```

Comment: OK understood re: resolve. But can you clarify where all these parts of code actually go? Where is the user variable that is the argument to `$firebaseObject` actually coming from? And this `$loaded` code goes in each and every controller to obtain the current user? Is there no way I can reuse something to obtain this current user e.g. a service/factory? In addition, could you clarify whether my code to triangulate the user from the uid and key is correct?